# Bash way to determine if operating system is OEL 5 or OEL 6?

Tags: linux, bash

Curious if there is a quick and cheap way to determine if the operating system a script is running on is either Oracle Linux 5 or Oracle Linux 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not super portable but you could try `lsb_release -r`.

Comment: Thanks, I used http://pastebin.com/dQ7EWuq1 which worked perfectly. Plus 1 and waiting to accept.